# Is there a way to have a single field behave as a text field and a file upload/browser at the same time?

Tags: 7

I need an option for users to have a single field behave as both a textfield so they can enter an external url or browse/upload field depending on which one they want to use. Having two fields will be confusing for users. Is this possible?

Comment: It is certainly possible, although I think it would require you to write your own field type. (Removed UX related part of comment that doesn't belong on DA)

Comment: IMHO The KISS approach here would be to write/find an editor (widget) that does this, rather than trying to configure Drupal in a roundabout way to allow this. Not being familiar with many of them, I'm unsure if any of the popular open ones (FCK, etc.) have this built in.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the users have to decide what type of data they want to enter. An option would be to let them choose and then show the appropriate field only. The [condotional field module](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) could comme in handy here.

Answer (score 0):

You can include 1 text field for the external URL and 1 Browse/Upload button to directly upload a file. That should keep your users from getting confused.